# Setting spring profile using Ant

Tags: java, spring, ant

Is it possible to set the spring profile using Ant? I tried googling it and found that a property named spring.profiles.active has to be set but couldn't find out how to set it using Ant `<sysproperty>` tag as I am new to both Ant and Spring.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ANT_OPTS` to set the system property and launch it from the commandline like this:

```
ANT_OPTS="-Dspring.profiles.active=myProfile" ant myTarget
```

Another option is to set it per JUnit test:

```
<junit fork="no">
  <sysproperty key="spring.profiles.active" value="myProfile"/>
</junit>
```

Example using TestNG

```
<testng>
   <jvmarg value="-Dspring.profiles.active=myProfile" />
   ...
</testng>
```

Comment: is there a cleaner way where I don't   have to use the command line at all.

Comment: yes, I need two separate profiles for my tests. Each profile should be set at runtime using a separate Ant build target.

Comment: added a `sysproperty` example